# In a Google account (sync), what is the difference between Contacts and People details?

Tags: contacts, sync, 4.4-kitkat

For a Google account, you are allowed to sync `Contacts` and `People details`. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The best explanation I could find [online](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-razr-maxx/249967-people-details-sync.html#post2455458):

> People Details is a new sync service related to the recent release of
>   Google Play Games. It was pushed to most (if not all) android devices
>   recently. Its purpose is to tie you together across all Google Play
>   services (the separate services available from the Google Play
>   screen). The idea is to maintain a uniform and unique "identity" for
>   you in all related Google Games so that data from one can potentially
>   be used to "enhance" the user experience in another

The contact sync is for the usual contacts that a user saves directly on your phone.

Answer (score 16):

- *Contacts* is for syncing contacts with [Google contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts). The information is the one specified by Android contacts (email, phone number, etc)
- *People details* is for syncing information with Google play and Google+, such as the Google+ profile picture, fit, Play game profiles, etc. The information is Google-specific.