# How do I remove Google contacts?

Tags: google-contacts

I have 3 Google accounts which have a bunch of auto-populated email addresses and contacts *I have never intended to add to my Android.*

I went to Settings > Accounts > Google > foobar@gmail.com > Contacts > Switched to **OFF**.

*However*, when I go back to the phone app, all of the garbage auto-populated email addresses are *still there*. And when I select one of them, it clearly indicates with a Google logo it was "synced from Google account".

I intentionally don't use Google stuff. I want it off my phone.

If relevant, I'm using Samsung Galaxy S6 on Android 5.1 Lollipop.

Comment: I haven't done that, and thus can only give an "educated guess": You've already switched of sync for those accounts you don't want the contacts from. Make a backup from the others, just to be safe. Then go to *Settings › Apps*, select the "All" tab, and check for something like "contact storage" (not sure how it's called *exactly* on Lollipop). Chose to delete its cache and data. That gets you rid of *all* contacts on your device – and afterwards, only those from the accounts with sync enabled should be sync'd back to it.

Comment: LineageOS + pico gApps is a very difficult phone overhaul that can do this.

Comment: LineageOS *without* any GApps is the better solution. Especially when the OP states "I intentionally don't use Google stuff. I want it off my phone." If you need parts of that: microG provides a compatible API that replaces "things Google" by "things FOSS" – e.g. the maps API uses OSM, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

You have done half the work.

By this [query](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60894/in-a-google-account-sync-what-is-the-difference-between-contacts-and-people-d), we can understand that this new *Google's people details sync* should be turned off too together with *Google contacts* as this new service connecting you with others via some other platforms such as Google+.

Follow these steps:

*Go to Contacts app - Open contact's settings (by touching 3 dots on the upper right corner) - Contacts to display (select account from which you want contacts from such as from 'phone contacts' or from a specific 'Google account'.*

It's done.

Attaching pictures to see inside settings of contacts app.

[image: Contact app settings]

Note: Be specific with an account as you can see in the picture Samsung is taking contacts from all the apps that are *Telegram, Paytm, Hike, and even from Samsung Pay.*

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to do is go here [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com). Log in with your account from which you want to delete contacts and then delete any contact you want from here. Once deleted from here, they'll be deleted from everywhere.

Comment: What if I want them there but not on my phone?

Comment: @Jonathan Just untick contact sync in settings-accounts-google and delete those contacts from your phone.